# $|x| + |x-1| = 3$ how come its cases?

Tags: modules, problem-solving

$$|x| + |x-1| = 3$$

in my textbook, they say that for this equation, there are 3 cases:

$x\geq1$,
$0 \leq x < 1$ and
$ x < 0$

where do these come from and why?  i thought, there are 4 cases

$x$ positive
$x-1$ positive

$x$ is negative
$x-1$ is negative

$x$ positive
$x-1$ is negative

$x$ is negative
$x-1$ is positive

Comment: The former is for both functions to be positive. The middle one is for one function to be positive and the other negative. The last is for both functions to be negative. Also, this is not a dumb question; its always good to revise.

Comment: This is pretty similar to your previous question. What have you tried?

Comment: Your edit is wrong: $|x|$ can't be negative; x can. Also, if $x<0, \ x-1$ can't be positive

Comment: @Alex oh thats why the last 4th case isnot there?

Comment: @doniyor: you have a lot of explanation for cases in the comments. Obviously if $x<0$ there's no way to make $x-1$ positive.

Comment: @Alex you are right, sorry for dumb question :(

Comment: @doniyor: you are welcome. The question is not dumb, but it's desirable to show your work when you ask it.

Comment: @Alex yep, i will next time :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the absolute value. Sometimes $|a|$ is $a$ and sometimes $|a|$ is $-a$. 
Here we have the cases

- $x\ge1$, where $|x-1|=x-1$ and collatrally also $|x|=x$.
- $x<0$, where $|x|=-x$ and also $|x-1|=1-x$
- the intermediate case $0\le x<1$, where $|x|=x$, but $|x-1|=1-x$.

In each case, replacing the absolute value expression with the corresponing absoluteness-less expression for the case in question gives us a simple equation that can be solved.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, both $x$ and $x-1$ are non-negative. In the second case, $x$ is non-negative but $x-1$ is negative.  In the last case, both $x$ and $x-1$ are negative.

Answer (score 2):

The 4 cases are entirely correct, but with a little bit of reasoning, they can be reduced to the 3 described by your book:

Let's see how the first modulus (A) behaves:

1. $|x| = x$, for $x >= 0$
2. $|x| = -x$, for $x < 0$

Now for the second (B):

1. $|x-1| = x-1$, for $x - 1 >= 0$ ($x >= 1$)
2. $|x-1| = 1-x$, for $x - 1 < 0$ ($x < 1$)

The equation becomes:

- **A1B1:** $x + x-1 = 3$, for $x >= 0$ and $x >= 1$
- **A1B2:** $x + 1-x = 3$, for $x >= 0$ and $x < 1$
- **A2B1:** $-x + x-1 = 3$, for $x < 0$ and $x >= 1$
- **A2B2:** $-x + 1-x = 3$, for $x < 0$ and $x < 1$

You can clearly see that A2B1 is invalid because $x$ can't be smaller than $0$ and larger than $1$ at the same time (which is the case you have found but has been silently excluded from the book).
A1B1 and A2B2 conditions can also be simplified to $x >= 1$ / $x < 0$ respectively, coming up with the cases from the book.

---

Another way to think about your problem is to see what intervals to analyze for $x$ by seeing the interesting values. $-Infinity$, $Infinity$ are always interesting and the other two interesting values are $0$ and $1$ (the values where the modulus functions change behavior).

Plotting the Numbers axis with these values highlighted looks like this:

$-Infinity$ **________** 0 **____** 1 **_______** $Infinity$

and this immediately makes it obvious that you have 3 intervals to check.

Comment: thank you very much, very nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value function does different things depending on whether the quantity inside the bars is positive or negative.  In this case:

1. $x-1$ is positive if $x > 1$, in which case $|x-1|$ is just equal to $x-1$.
2. $x-1$ is negative if $x<1$, in which case $|x-1$ is equal to $-(x-1)$ (or if you prefer $1-x$).
3. On the other hand $|x|$ equals just $x$ if $x>0$.
4. And $|x|$ equals $-x$ if $x<0$.

If you look at those four statements you'll notice that there are really three regions in which the behavior of the expression needs to be considered separately.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

|x| is either +x or -x, depending on the value of x. Same with |x-1|. So for each absolute value, you consider the case that the argument is >= 0, and the case that the argument is <= 0. That's two cases for each absolute value, and two altogether.

If x >= 1, then both x and x-1 are >= 0, and |x| = x, |x-1| = x-1.

If 0 <= x < 1, then x >= 0 but x-1 < 0, so |x| = x, |x-1| = - (x-1)

and so on. There is no possible value x where x < 0 but x-1 >= 0, so only three of the four cases are possible.